# find character and Insert a new line in the file

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to read a file line by line and once I reach a line that doesn't contain the same characters in columns 65 - 67 I want to insert a string line 2 lines above that. I am using VB.NET

So far I have written code that reads the file line by line.
I am unsure how to insert a string line to a file where characters in columns 65-67 are different
any help would be great. Thanks

```
   Protected Sub UploadFile(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") & fileName
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath)

    '--Read block of lines then insert line for each new block
    For Each line In IO.File.ReadLines(filePath)
        'If line.Substring(65, 3) <> " " Then '<> to previous substring

            '--Insert new line 

        'End If
    Next

End Sub



 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Upload File" runat="server" OnClick="UploadFile" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
    Dim lines As List(Of String) = IO.File.ReadLines(filePath).ToList
    Dim idx As Integer = 0
    Do While idx < lines.Count - 2
        Dim thisLine As String = lines(idx)
        Dim nextLine As String = lines(idx + 1)
        If thisLine.Substring(65, 3) <> nextLine.Substring(65, 3) Then
            lines.Insert(idx + 1, "NEW BLOCK")
            idx += 1
        End If
        idx += 1
    Loop
    Dim foo As String = String.Join(ControlChars.Cr, lines)
    IO.File.WriteAllText("path", foo)
```

**edit - based on comments**

```
    Dim lines As List(Of String) = IO.File.ReadLines(filePath).ToList
    Dim idx As Integer = 0
    Do While idx < lines.Count - 2
        Dim thisLine As String = lines(idx)
        Dim nextLine As String = lines(idx + 1)
        Dim key As String = thisLine.Substring(65, 3).Trim
        If key <> nextLine.Substring(65, 3) AndAlso
                key = "" Then
            lines.Insert(idx + 1, "NEW BLOCK")
            idx += 1
        End If
        idx += 1
    Loop
    Dim foo As String = String.Join(ControlChars.Cr, lines)
    IO.File.WriteAllText("path", foo)
```

Comment: @Martha - it was intended to show how you can go about this.  You can change the check to meet your needs.

Comment: This code adds "NEW BLOCK" to the second line. I should clarify it is not always every second line I want it to be inserted. therefore I cannot use Dim nextLine As String = lines(idx + 1). Instead I want it inserted when Substring(65, 3) is not nothing AND is differnt than the previous. this code inserts only after first two rows instead of infront of  row  containing 04592160

Comment: thank you for your code. I am still unsure as to how to read lines and only insert "New Block" where Substring(65, 3) is not null and is different than the last

Comment: @Martha - see edit above